# "Uncaught Throw[Null]","VBundleOfMetric" and "MetricsOfVBundle" when using package "xAct"

Tags: xact

The codes are below:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
```

Then:

```
Index = IndexRange[a, m]
DefManifold[M, 4, Index]
DefMetric[-1, metric[-a, -b], CD, PrintAs -> "g"]
```

As I press down shift and enter,it reads:"`VBundleOfMetric:Unknown metric Removed[metric]`".
And I tried to use EulerDensity in xTras:

```
GBterm = NoScalar @ EulerDensity[CD]
```

it reads:"`MetricOfVBundle:Unknown vbundle Removed[TangentM]`" and "`Throw:Uncaught Throw[Null] to top level`".

I don't know how this happens,and try to reopen the file but failed.

Comment: In general, it is better to use `ClearAll` rather than `Remove`. Perhaps this will solve your issue, in addition to the advice of the existing answer.

Answer (score 2):

It appears `` Remove["Global`*"] `` is not that safe in `xact`: as you can see, the error refers to `Removed[TangentM]` meaning that `xact` still had a reference to it. You can try restarting the kernel instead of running `` Remove["Global`*"] ``. Another alternative to `Remove[...]` is to use `Undef*` functions provided by `xact` like `UndefManifold[M]`. It is also generally advised against introducing variables starting from a capital letter (like `Index` you are using) to avoid the conflict with Mathematica definitions. I started a new kernel and ran

```
<< xAct`xTensor`;
<< xAct`xTras`;
ii = IndexRange[a, m];
DefManifold[M, 4, ii];
DefMetric[-1, metric[-a, -b], CD, PrintAs -> "g"];
GBterm = NoScalar@EulerDensity[CD]
```

and the issue didn't reproduce.